# Highcharts Angular - Unable to access addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown and applyDrilldown in drilldown event

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using drilldown event to asynchronously add the drilldown in my chart.

```
events: {
    drilldown: function(e): void {
        if (!e.seriesOptions) {
            // e.point.name is info which bar was clicked
            this.showLoading('Simulating Ajax ...');
            const outer = {
                type: 'pie',
                size: '100%',
                innerSize: '75%',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                zIndex: 1,
                name: 'Cars',
                data: [
                    {
                        name: 'Other',
                        y: 24,
                        drilldown: 'true',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'abc',
                        y: 7,
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'def',
                        y: 3,
                    }
                ]
            } as Highcharts.SeriesOptionsType

            this.hideLoading();
            this.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, outer); <------- HERE
            this.applyDrilldown(); <-------- And HERE
        }
    },
},
```

But somehow angular doesn't recognize the methods addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown and applyDrilldown as part of 'this'.

Please refer screenshot below :
[methodNotAvailable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9qOX.png)

But the thing is, if I skip this validation using eslint :

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call, @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
(this as any).addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, outer);
```

Then it compiles fine and works fine at runtime also.

Any idea how can I make my angular compiler to recognize these methods?

Answer (score 0):

The `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` method is internal, so you need to create your own type that will extend the `Highcharts.Chart`. For example:

```
interface ExtendedChart extends Highcharts.Chart {
  addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(
    point: Highcharts.Point,
    options: Highcharts.SeriesOptionsType
  ): void;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-a-custom-plugin-btw9ff?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#property-xxx-does-not-exist-on-type-yyy

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeriesAsDrilldown